# Swing components freezing until one component completes its job

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, swingworker

I have created a simple JAVA Swing program that has a JTextArea, three JTextFields and one JButton. What this application does is when the user clicks the button it updates the JTextArea with a text line, the text line inserted into the JTextArea is prepared in a for loop and number of repeat times is given in a JTextField.

My problem is when I click the start JButton all the components of the application are freeze, I can't even close the window until the for loop completes it's  job. How can I separate this JTextField updating work from other tasks in the form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably doing the work on the Event Dispatch Thread (the same thread as the GUI rendering is done). Use [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) it will do the work in another thread instead.

---

### Example

Code below produces this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

**Example worker:**

```
static class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<String, String> {

    private final JTextArea area;

    MyWorker(JTextArea area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            publish("Processing... " + i);
        }
        return "Done";
    }
    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String c : chunks) area.insert(c + "\n", 0);
    }
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            area.insert(get() + "\n", 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Example `main`:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Execute") {            
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new MyWorker(area).execute();
        }
    }), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example how to implement this?

Comment: *"Can you give me an example..?"* I can give [100](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SwingWorker+).  I figure there must be 100 examples among those 500+ hits (besides the example already linked in the answer).

Comment: This is a good answer, except I think a `SwingWorker` should be executed by an [`Executor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) in lieu of direct execution (from the `SwingWorker`) for real-world implementations. This allows you to encapsulate thread launching behavior inside a single object.