# SwingWorker with FileReader

Tags: java, netbeans, swingworker

I have problem about applied SwingWorker with FileReader and my point is I need to implement FileReader with SwingWorker to make my UI Show the text from the file and this is my code

```
class Read1 extends SwingWorker<String,String>{
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception{
        FileReader read = new FileReader("msg.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
        String s;
        s=in.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }
   protected void done()
    {
      try{
       String show;
       show=get();
       textArea.append(show);}catch(Exception e){}}

 public static void main(String args[]) {
   Read1 r = new Form().new Read1();
   r.execute();
```

However it does not append anything on the UI textarea

anyone have solution? Thank you

Comment: First of all, never do this: `catch(Exception e){}`. Log your exception and see what's wrong. Second - that code does not even compile. Post a simple working example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I already compile and run that the output is become gui but it doesn't append anything on the textarea

Comment: Check out [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524800/swing-components-freezing-untill-one-component-complete-its-job).

Comment: @dacwe I'm already applied this example to my project however it still does not work

Comment: @user1539677: What doesn't work?

Comment: First I make Thread sleep in doInBackground then I publish string s from s = in.readline then I create process method by using public void process(List<String> chunks){ for(String c: chunks) Textarea.insert(c + "\n", 0); but it still not work

Comment: Can you verify that the text is been read.  This may be a layout issue.  Also, when done is called, dump the contents of the `textArea` to the console `System.out.println(textArea.getText())`

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for me:

```
public class Reader extends SwingWorker<List<String>, String> {

    protected List<String> doInBackground() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<String> lstText = new ArrayList<String>(25);

        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {

        FileReader read = new FileReader("Scanner.txt");
        in = new BufferedReader(read);
        String s = null;

        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {

            lstText.add(s);
            publish(s);

        }

        } finally {


            try {

                in.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        return lstText;

    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {

        for (String text : chunks) {

            fldText.append(text + "\n");

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to ask you more , how can I repeat working of the SwingWorker ?

Comment: SwingWorkers are non-reentrant.  That means, once you've called `execute`, it can not be `execute`ed again, you will need to create a new instance.  However, in the `doInBackground` you can loop - this does mean that the execution will continue, `done` won't be called and `get` will block

Comment: So what solution that I need if the situation is I am the receiver and when I finish read this text file then I remove file to other directory and when sender send the new text file  my GUI need to show it again without using any button

Comment: If you ave to read the file again, I'd say you'll want to create a new instance of te work, keeps things simple & isolated